# Can the text in label contain eval?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, label, eval

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblprodId" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("flavourID") %>"></asp:Label>
```

I got parser error when i run this page.When I change it.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblprodId" runat="server" Text=""><%# Eval("flavourID") %></asp:Label>
```

When i run this page there is no error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use to consider that a parser error. You can get this working doing this:

```cs
<asp:Label ID="lblprodId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("flavourID") %>'></asp:Label>
```

*Note: I changed double quotes with single quotes.*